# OroCRM stuck in system requirement (app/cache)

Tags: orocrm

I am stuck in the orocrm platform application installation. It gives me this error at requirement check. I have tried to clear the cache but it still gives me this error.

Anyone can help me to solve this error?

```
 ERROR   | Move app/cache folder outside encrypted directory.
```

Jake

Comment: Did you installed OroCRM?